# JW Player 6 Plugin for Wordpress edit jwplayer.js for white background

Tags: javascript, html5-video, jwplayer6

**I have:**

- Wordpress V4.4.1
- JW Player 6 Plugin for Wordpress - Version 2.1.14

**I have fixed a few things, which are:**

- Remove blue border when you click on the video `outline:0;`
- Reduce bottom margin a little when you responsive design `margin-bottom: 
  -11px;`

*The CSS code looks like this:*

```
#jwplayer-0
{
outline:0;
margin-bottom: -11px;
}
```

**The Problem - Black bars / background**

- When zooming in & out via chrome/FF, you get a 1px bar on the
  left/right or top. this is for the HTML5 player.
- All my videos have a white background and also the preview image has a white background, thus the 1px bar is annoying.

**Solution**
After reading endless sites and posts I have determined that I need to edit:

- jwplayer.js
- jwplayer.html5.js

As stated in this post [Video embed background color](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/5405666-video-embed-background-color)

I have searched the plugin folder **jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress** bit I cannot find these files. I assume they are being called from a remote server, are they? I have even search all the code for background-color etc using Notepad++, nothing comes up.

Does anyone know how to change video embed background color using the plugin?

Here's the code used in WP for the video:

```
[jwplayer player='2' abouttext='test' aboutlink='http://www.test.com' primary='html5' image='/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/test.jpg' jwplayer sources="{ file:'/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/test.webm' },{ file:'/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/test.mp4' }"]
```

- WEBM - Video for CHROME/FF - Fixes grey video
- MP4 - For all mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using WebM and MP4 media types, the player should be rendering in HTML5 mode - as per the "primary" setting.

Given this, you should be able to target the player using CSS and override the background color:

```
.jwplayer{background-color:transparent!important;}
```